# Negative lookahead in singleline regex

Tags: regex

I have following test string:

```
/// <exception cref="x"><paramref name="a"/> is null.</exception>
/// <exception cref="y"><paramref name="b"/> is null. -or-
/// </exception>dfjhhdfhdfkjhdkjdfhkdfjhdf -or-
```

It's a three-line string. So I've created regex with Singleline flag to capture new lines with dot. My regex is:

```
(<exception.+?>)(?<a>.+?)(?!<\/exception>)-or-
```

With this regex I expect to match only second line. But what I get is (visualized with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)):

[image]

First two lines are matched and second group includes `</exception>` although I've specified negative lookahead `(?!<\/exception>)`.

Why this happened? How can I match second line relying on presense of `-or-`?

Comment: What are you trying to match here, and what is the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be overkill, but you could use a tempered dot to match the `-or-` without passing a closing tag:

```
<exception[^>]*>((?!</exception>).)*-or-
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to:

```
<exception[^>]*>      match an opening <exception> tag
((?!</exception>).)*  then match any content WITHOUT passing a closing </exception> tag
-or-                  match -or-
```